# ssi.php return strange page

Tags: php, integration, ssi, ipb

I include in some pages this code:

```
$_GET['a'] = 'stats2';
include "/var/www/forum/ssi.php";
```

on main page (www.musite.com) its work fine. But on other pages like www.mysite.com/bigpage/, www.mysite.com/about/ etc. **ssi.php** return part of forum page (a lot of css an js).

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the exact same code you are using in your application? It sounds like your linking to a relative path..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My version IPB 3.1.2, FURL on.

The problem in FURL's.

There is a call FURL check function in ipsRegistry::instance()->init().

Before exit init() function it check FURL:

```
/* Have we entered an incorrect FURL that has no match? */
    if ( ipsRegistry::$settings['use_friendly_urls'] AND self::$_noFurlMatch === true )
    {
        self::getClass('output')->showError( 'incorrect_furl', 404, null, null, 404 );
    }
    else if( isset(ipsRegistry::$request['act']) AND ipsRegistry::$request['act'] == 'rssout' )
    {
        self::getClass('output')->showError( 'incorrect_furl', 404, null, null, 404 );
    }
```

That's why it pull 404 error and include a lot of forum html.